# Add object to JSON in JSON .NET

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, function, class

I have this simple class for mapping JSON to C#:

```
Public Class AtributeRaport
    Public Property NumeRaport As String
    Public Property ApplicationId As String
    Public Property ObjectId As String
    Public Property Selections As String
    Public Property Deprecated As String
End Class

Public Class Rapoarte
    Public Property Id As String
    Public Property AtributeRaport As List(Of AtributeRaport)
End Class
```

I have this `Sub`, so far, for adding objects to the JSON file:

```
Sub AddToJson(id As String, nume As String, appId As String, objectId As String, selections As String, deprecated As String)
        Dim filePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "\reports.json"
        Dim jsonData = IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath)
        Dim jsonroot As List(Of Rapoarte) = If(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Rapoarte))(jsonData), New List(Of Rapoarte))

        Dim attrlist = New AtributeRaport With {
            .ApplicationId = appId,
            .NumeRaport = nume,
            .ObjectId = objectId,
            .Selections = selections,
            .Deprecated = deprecated
            }
        jsonroot.Add(New Rapoarte With {.Id = id, .AtributeRaport = New List(Of AtributeRaport)})

        Dim serializerSettings As New JsonSerializerSettings
        serializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        serializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonroot, serializerSettings)
        IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonData)
    End Sub
```

If I run this, the output is:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "AtributeRaport": []
  }
]
```

For the life of me, I don't know how to add those pesky values which I declare in my `attrlist`.

Also, if I want to get all the values under a certain `id`, from JSON, would this approach work:

```
Public Function GetAttributesJson(id As String, filepath As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim jObject As JObject = JObject.Load(New JsonTextReader(File.OpenText(filepath)))
        Dim attrlist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim resources As JArray = CType(jObject("id"), JArray)
        For Each attr In resources.Where(Function(obj) obj("id").Value(Of String) Is id.ToString)
            attrlist.Add(attr("ApplicationId").Value(Of String))
            attrlist.Add(attr("NumeRaport").Value(Of String))
            attrlist.Add(attr("ObjectId").Value(Of String))
            attrlist.Add(attr("Selections").Value(Of String))
            attrlist.Add(attr("Deprecated").Value(Of String))
        Next
        Return attrlist
    End Function
```

Thank you so much for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.AtributeRaport` is not assigned to '`attrlist`'   which might be causing this issue

```
  jsonroot.Add(New Rapoarte With {.Id = id, .AtributeRaport = (New List(Of AtributeRaport) From {
            attrlist})})
```